# NullReferenceException after Install Wizard for DotNetNuke 6.1.1 on Azure

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, azure-sql-database, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm trying to migrate an existing 6.01.01 site to Windows Azure web pages for testing some new features. I had so much trouble going about doing so that I decided to start over and just get version 6.1.1 running on Azure from the community install. Now I'm running into an error when I finish the InstallWizard. The exception in the log is as follows:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an  object.
at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.InitializePage()
at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Does anyone have any idea on what might be causing this or even how to debug it? I'm very new to Azure and DNN.

NOTE: In order to get the InstallWizard to work I had to make a few changes to the web.config file. They are as follows:

- replace the default db string with our SQL azure string
- put in a long request timeout
- comment out the url rewriting modules